# How to change the type of the data in text box?

Tags: html, date, textbox, master-pages

I want my text box to have a date in it, how do I do it?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="BirthdayRegBt" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Birthday Date" required=""></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the placeholder attribute to indicate a sample value for the field. For Date, there are HTML 5 input types such as date, datetime, datetime-local are available.

for. e.g.

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  TextMode="DateTimeLocal"  placeholder="12-12-2016" ></asp:TextBox>

html example:

Comment: how do I do it withoit the hour? Also, can I put a place holder that is text?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="placeholderTextBox" runat="server" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtBalochistanExpireDate" runat="server" MaxLength="50" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control" DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" DisplayDateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" />

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work.

```
<asp:TextBox Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Date", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>' ID="txtDate" runat="server" placeholder="Date" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: It shows error cs1061 "'Control' does not contain a definition for 'DateItem' and no accessible extension method 'DateItem' accepting a first argument of type 'Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"